# Cannot install libevent on CentOS 6.5

Tags: software-installation, package-management, compiling, amazon-ec2

I'm on CentOS 6.5. Specifically, I'm running this AMI: [Adobe Media Server 5 Extended](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00IGJMIOI).

I followed these steps:

```
$ sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
$ sudo yum install glib2-devel fuse-devel libevent-devel \
    libxml2-devel openssl-devel

$ wget https://github.com/downloads/libevent/libevent/libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz

$ tar -xzf libevent-2.0.21-stable.tar.gz
$ cd libevent-2.0.21-stable

$ ./configure && make
$ sudo make install

$ sudo echo "/usr/local/lib/" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/riofs.conf
$ sudo ldconfig
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Then do `libevent` and I get `command not found`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libevent is library. library most often doesn't go with any executables, so "command not found" for executable with same name as library is perfectly fine.

Comment: That makes sense. Another project that I'm trying to install is giving me errors saying that it can't find `libevent`. It might be a problem with that project, though.

Answer (score 1):

When you did the `sudo make install` the command `libevent` was installed into some directory that's likely not on your `$PATH`, assuming that there is a `libevent` command in the first place. You can confirm this using the command:

```
$ type -f libevent
```

If it was in a directory on the `$PATH` it would return something like this:

```
$ type -f java
java is /usr/bin/java
```

It's likely that your software was installed under `/usr/local/`. I'd run this command to find `libevent`.

```
$ find /usr/local -name "libevent"
```

If it returns back a location then you should be able to use the full path to run `libevent`:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/libevent
```